# How to add time pattern in the log when using java logger

Tags: java, logging

We use java.util.logging, and we use java.util.logging.FileHandler to config the rotated logs.

We want to add timestamp into log file name pattern to make it looks like:

```
logFile_2011-08-25_14_*02*_38_PDT.0.log
logFile_2011-08-25_14_*12*_38_PDT.1.log
logFile_2011-08-25_14_*22*_38_PDT.2.log
logFile_2011-08-25_14_*32*_38_PDT.3.log
```

Be aware of the different timestamp in the log file name.

We are now using the pattern = "logfile_XXXXXX.%g"

How is the pattern looks like to make the timestamp decided at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, java.util.logging no! Check out [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) instead! It's a successor of [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) and of course implements [sfl4j](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Back to your question, I'm not an expert of Java Logging but I believe you cannot do this through configuration. There might be other ways though..